# What is the image under the curtain in God of War?

Tags: god-of-war-2018

So, at the end of the campaign, Kratos and Atreus reach their goal.

> On the wall, they discover "their story" had been foretold by the Giants. Atreus goes ahead, and the wind blows, revealing another image.

What does this represent?

Comment: haven't not seen it i would guess going by the context it maybe a hint to a sequel?

Comment: We won't know what it means untill a future game tells us

Comment: @JoeryJV if the location is an actual rendered object then datamining could reveal what texture is used there. On the other hand if it's not intended to be visible then whatever texture is used might not have any relevance to what is officially revealed later. I don't know whether any significant datamining effort has been done for God of War either way.

Comment: I feel that these comments are the answer to the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The image in question is here:

[image: God of War ending]

This appears to be Atreus holding a dying Kratos, with something coming out of (or going into) Atreus's mouth.

As far as I know this did not happen in this game, so it's most likely foreshadowing something that will happen in a sequel.